# How to find element with dynamic id through Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to using webdriver in Python with Selenium and have run into a barrier on something I am working on to automate some data extraction from a webportal. I am trying to enter a date into a textbox, but I my script returns a `NoSuchElementException` no matter which way I try to search for the element.

Using Chrome, I can use the below ID to easily identify the element in the inspect window, but finding it with Python has been impossible.

HTML element I am trying to isolate:

```
input id="6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-toDate" type="text" value="01/15/2019" size="10" maxlength="10" onchange="validateDateField('to', '6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-fromDate', '6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-toDate', '6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-absRangeErr')"
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
from_date = driver.find_elements_by_id("6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-fromDate")
from_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-fromDate']")
from_date = from_date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-fromDate']")
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: sytax look fine but I can see that maybe you are using a wrong id. If the id of your input is : "6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-toDate" why are you trying to find this one: "6A8A7718100001256A44465A5ED3AEAC-fromDate"?

Comment: Good catch, I have two text boxes (one "fromDate, one "toDate") and I was testing to see if either of them could work. I've made an edit to avoid any further confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The alphanumeric characters before the '-toDate' seem to be auto generated. This means that they may change between builds of the site or may be dynamically created when the js runs.

Therefore I would use the contains keyword in xpath as it should be more robust against these changes.

```
to_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, '-toDate')]")
from_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, '-fromDate')]")
```

Comment: Thanks cullzie! The main issue was that the element was in an iframe and I was unaware I had to switch over to that before looking for the nested element. Your solution should help a lot moving forward now that I am in the correct window.

Answer (score 0):

To send a *date* i.e. a *character sequence* into the textbox as the desired element is a *dynamic* element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='-toDate'][onchange*='-toDate']"))).send_keys("01/16/2019")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, '-toDate') and contains(@onchange, '-toDate')]"))).send_keys("01/16/2019")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB, the link to the exceptions saved me here. The element I needed was in an iframe and I had to switch over to it before searching.